# how can i find the sum of the first five results in a file

Tags: python-3.x

I have a file, every last number in a line is the result.
How can I find the sum of the first five results ?

items in file:
50.0-5.0:45.00
23.0+23.0:46.00
23.0-23.0:0.00
23.0+24.0:47.00
23.0*2.0:46.00
23.0-20.0:3.00
20.0/10.0:2.00

Comment: split on `:`, and for the first five lines `sum` the `float` of the string parts?

Comment: Explain the format of the file. Despite of that it seems to be a classic of "divide and conquer": Extract the first five lines, extract the last number from those, sum the numbers. I think each of those steps is very easy to do, and you should have tried harder yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read as much of the file as necessary (first 5 rows) and sum the "results", i.e., last field in `:`-delimited rows, omitting the `newline` character at the end of the row.

```py
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> with open('/path/to/file') as f:
...     a_sum = sum(float(row.rstrip().split(':')[1]) for row in islice(f,5))
... 
>>> a_sum
184.0
```

or without importing `islice`

```py
>>> a_sum = 0
>>> with open('/path/to/file') as f:
...     for i, row in enumerate(f,1):
...        a_sum += float(row.rstrip().split(':')[1])
...        if i == 5:
...            break
... 
>>> a_sum
184.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
In [1]: content = open("test.txt").readlines()

In [2]: content = content[:5]

In [3]: content
Out[3]:
['50.0-5.0:45.00\n',
 '23.0+23.0:46.00\n',
 '23.0-23.0:0.00\n',
 '23.0+24.0:47.00\n',
 '23.0*2.0:46.00\n']

In [4]: results = [line.split(":")[-1].strip() for line in content]

In [5]: results
Out[5]: ['45.00', '46.00', '0.00', '47.00', '46.00']

In [6]: sum(map(float, results))
Out[6]: 184.0
```

- read the file
- truncate the list of lines to first 5 elements
- extract the results from the list of lines
- parse the results as `float`, then add them up using `sum`